# How to make Legend for Core Plot bubble chart

Tags: core-plot, legend, scatter-plot, bubble-chart

I have made a bubble chart using a coreplot scatterplot by adjusting the size of each symbol in the data source method

```
-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {
    Event *thisEvent;
    CGSize size;
    CPTPlotSymbol *symbol;

    symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [symbol.lineStyle mutableCopy];

    if (idx < self.events.count) {
        thisEvent = [self.events objectAtIndex:idx];
        size.width = [thisEvent scaledValue];
        size.height = size.width;
   }
}
```

How can I create a legend showing the values for each of several symbol sizes?  I've been looking at CPTLegendEntry in the [class reference](https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_legend.html#a49fa9dffd59dc365d811da971418f345), but haven't been able to work it out yet.  If anyone out there can help (Eric?), i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a legend delegate to customize drawing the swatches. Implement the `- legend:shouldDrawSwatchAtIndex:forPlot:inRect:inContext:` delegate method and draw your custom swatch into the given context. Return `NO` to tell the legend that it doesn't need to draw the default swatch, too.

If you need more control, you can create your own. Subclass `CPTBorderedLayer`, override `-renderAsVectorInContext:` to do the drawing, and attach the custom layer to the graph as an annotation.